# undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf'

Tags: c

I am compiling a C code program on SUSE 11 SP3,and it always put the error just like the title showed.And I try my best to search some ways to fix it up.Unfortunately, they doesn't work.

```
aa/lib/sftp_fsmeg_proc.o /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_obm.a /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp.a /si/usr/aa/lib/fisc_app.a /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_app.a /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_db.a /si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a /si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a -lclntsh `cat /home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/ldflags`   `cat /home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/sysliblist` -ldl -lm  
/si/usr/aa/lib/sftp_public.o：function ‘sftp_slip_filename’：
/si/usr/aa/src/arch/sftp/sftp_public.c:459：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
/si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a(arch_datetime.o)：function ‘arch_chk_date’：
/si/usr/aa/src/arch/arch_datetime.c:124：undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf'
/si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a(arch_datetime.o)：function ‘arch_chk_time’：
/si/usr/aa/src/arch/arch_datetime.c:375：undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf'
/si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a(arch_datetime.o)：function ‘arch_timestr_to_time’：
/si/usr/aa/src/arch/arch_datetime.c:847：undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf'
```

My gcc version is 4.3.4,and libc is 2.11.3.

```
$gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$/lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.11.3 (20110527), by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Configured for x86_64-suse-linux.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973].
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.32 system on 2013-05-10.
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

And I try to write a miniel with the Line that the error info show,it seems work normal.When I add /lib64/libc.so.6,it also can compiles successfully.

```
$/usr/bin/gcc -m64 -fPIC -g -I . -DSFTP_DEBUG -I /si/usr/aa/include/arch -I /si/usr/aa/include/fisc/app -I /si/usr/aa/include/rtsc -I /si/usr/aa/include/rtsc/app -I /si/usr/aa/include/rtsc/db -I /si/usr/aa/include/arch -I /si/usr/aa/include/arch \
> -o sftp_server -m64  -L/home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/precomp/lib/ -L/home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/ -L/home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/stubs/ \
> -o sftp_server sftp_server.o /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp_server_proc.o /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp_public.o /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp_lzari.o /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp_fsmeg_proc.o /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_obm.a /si/usr/aa/lib/sftp.a /si/usr/aa/lib/fisc_app.a /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_app.a /si/usr/aa/lib/rtsc_db.a /si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a /si/usr/aa/lib/arch.a \
> -lclntsh `cat /home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/ldflags`   `cat /home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/sysliblist` -ldl **/lib64/libc.so.6** -lm 
$
```

Why?It is really puzzle me what's the wrong with.Can you give me some suggestion? Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=c99`.

Comment: Obviously your are missing a library for your linker phase. But this will be difficult to track, because your system is really oooold. A gcc in its 10th year, probably not many remember how the C library was implemented back then and why there was this `isoc99` prefix to some functions.

Comment: @JensGustedt
Yeah,maybe I am missing a library, but the same code and some makefile can work successfully on an other machine which also is Suse 11 SP3.And I have tried to make out their differences like env or libary path.But none of them toke affect.

Comment: @PaulR It seems not work.

Comment: hey, you found any solution ?